# How to give access to bot to my gmail account

Tags: google-docs-api

I have a bot ready, but when it tries to access my gmail account (to sort through my spam etc.) it keeps on getting blocked. How can I get it unblocked and authorized to access my gmail?

Comment: Try adding the APIs you're calling, the bot setup, code language, client framework. And what exactly is happening when it gets "blocked".

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide OAuth client through the developer console.

Goto https://console.developers.google.com/ and log in with your google account, from the my project dropdown select new project, give it a meaningful name and then create. Then select credential, create credentials -> OAuth client ID and complete the creation